# Bald cross eyed character on Family Guy

Tags: character, family-guy

I saw an episode of family guy and they had a parody of a comic strip character that I did not recognize:

[image]

Who is he?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is Opie (voiced by Mark Hentemann)

### [image]

> Opie is a mentally challenged ex-co-worker of Peter Griffin at the Pawtucket Brewery and ward of the state. He has won "Employee of the Month" at least twenty times and has been promoted ahead of Peter.
>
> He has a mental retardation and he never really does anything. He sometimes tells Peter to stick his finger in mouth, only to bite it. He wears two different shoes on each foot. He once went for a haircut that went horribly awry. No one other than Angela seems to understand what he's saying. However, Peter has been shown to understand him in in some instances such as when he gets fired

http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Opie

It is later revealed that Opie speaks gibberish because he is constantly drunk.